# Php reproduce a js script (convert to php script)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, replace

i would like to reproduce/convert this js script to a php script, is there anyone can help me?
i think i need preg_replace() in php and i'm really not good with it :/

this is my js simple script:

```
wysiwyg_val = $('.wysiwyg textarea').val()
.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
.replace(/<br>/g,'[br]')
.replace(/\</g,'&lt;')
.replace(/\>/g,'&gt;')
.replace(/\{code\}/g, '<pre><code>')
.replace(/\{\/code\}/g, '</code></pre>')
.replace(/\{strong\}/g, '<strong>')
.replace(/\{\/strong\}/g, '</strong>')
.replace(/\{italic\}/g, '<i>')
.replace(/\{\/italic\}/g, '</i>')
.replace(/\{title\}/g, '<h2>')
.replace(/\{\/title\}/g, '</h2>')
.replace(/\{subtitle\}/g, '<h3>')
.replace(/\{\/subtitle\}/g, '</h3>')
.replace(/\[br\]/g,'<br>');
```

the `wysiwyg_val`, after is escaped, is passed via Ajax to a php page which can take it as `$_POST['text']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$wysiwyg_val = 'xyz'; // your WYSIWYG input

$replacements = array(
    array('/\n/g', "<br>"),
    array('/<br>/g', '[br]'),
    array('/\</g','&lt;'),
    // and so forth.
);

foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
    $wysiwyg_val = preg_replace($replacement[0], $replacement[1], $wysiwyg_val);
}
```

Comment: do you think is this is faster then @queueoverflow code?

Comment: It is exactly the same speed. But you'll save yourself a lot of `$wysiwyg_val = preg_replace('/foo/g', 'bar', $wysiwyg_val);` lines.

Comment: it returns me an error : Unknown modifier 'g'  .. why does? :O

Comment: also doing a simple $text = preg_replace('/\n/g', "{br}{/br}", $text); maybe no \n is in $text?

Comment: ok sorry i founded that /g is not used in php cause it replaces always globally without of it ... or i'm mistaking?

Answer (score 2):

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

So just do

```
$subject = $POST['text'];

$subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
...
```

Comment: does the $pattern matches to the .replace() pattern i used in js? i mean can i put the same pattern both for js and php replace? :)

Comment: If you look at vzwick's answer, it seems like it.